# How to distribute jobs to multiple machines and keep same job on the same machine?

Tags: python, algorithm, hadoop, scheduling, distributed-computing

I have a list of 1000 jobs that needs to be ran periodically, I'm putting 5 machines to ran these jobs, each machine will check the list from top to bottom and find the first one that needs to be ran (by comparing `last_run_time` and current time and the `interval` value of that job it knows whether a job needs to be ran again) and ran it. While one machine starts running a job, it updates the job to say it's running so other machines won't double run it.

Job table in DB:

```
job_id | last_run_time | interval (sec)| running
  1         11:05            60           False
  2         07:12           100           True
 ...
1000        12:56          3000           False
```

**Each task can be ran 10% faster if ran on the same machine of last run** because it needs result from previous run, if on the same machine it doesn't need to download that, so I want that to happen as often as possible. I'm thinking about naming each machine and include machine names as an extra column (`last_run_on_machine`) of this table, but that's troublesome and I want to be able to add more machines or shut down some of the machines whenever I want. What's a good algorithm or if there exists some tool/library that can do this? I'm using Python, the DB is MySQL, completing each task takes about 10 - 60 seconds.

Comment: You should figure out why it's faster to run the same task on the same machine twice.

Comment: @amirouche  the job need result from previous run, if ran on the same machine it's already there, otherwise it needs to download.